# Incorrect Result: Formatting ISO-8601 Time And Extract 12 Hour Time

Tags: android, facebook, datetime, facebook-fql, iso8601

I am fetching Newsfeeds from the Facebook API using FQL which returns a "created_time" field as a UNIX Timestamp. I am converting that into, what I believe is a ISO-8601 timestamp using this piece of code:

```
String getInitialCreatedTime = JOFeeds.getString("created_time");
long finalTimeStamp = Long.valueOf(getInitialCreatedTime);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
String finalCreatedTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date(finalTimeStamp * 1000L));
```

Now, from the String, `finalCreatedTime` I want to extract just the time in 12 Hour (AM/PM) format.

To that effect, I am using this code:

```
final String old_format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
final String new_format = "EEE MMM d hh:mm aa yyyy";

String oldDateSring = finalCreatedTime;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(old_format);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateSring);
sdf.applyPattern(new_format);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
```

And:

```
// GET THE TIME
SimpleDateFormat sdfTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String getTime = sdfTimeFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
feeds.setTime(getTime);
Log.e("TIME", getTime);
```

The result of the first code block is: `2012-12-14T04:30:03+0530`

And the result from the `// GET THE TIME` block is `04:30AM` when it should be `04:30PM`.

I would appreciate any pointers on this. Perhaps, I am implementing it wrong?

EDIT: I might add, that timestamps that fall between 12.00 PM and 1.00 PM are handled properly and show PM as they should.

Comment: 04:30 looks like 4:30 AM to me.

Comment: @njzk2: It does actually. And that is where the problem lies. Perhaps I am making a mistake in converting the UNIX Timestamp. But it ought to be 04.30 PM. I have posted a solution that (so far) has worked well. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: in fact, the issue come from the fact that, rather than having one date object and simply formatting it, you format it, then parse it then format it again (why, by the way?). The formatting and parsing format are not compatible, as you use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ` first and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` later. (HH and hh are not the same, mind you)

Comment: @njzk2: Hmm... That makes sense. So I fix the HH and hh and that should do it?

Comment: @njzk2: Can you post your comment as an answer? Bringing parity to the `SimpleDateFormats` did the trick.

Comment: that should do it, but that's not a very clean approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :

```
String getInitialCreatedTime = JOFeeds.getString("created_time");
long finalTimeStamp = Long.valueOf(getInitialCreatedTime);
// Note 8601 is written with 'HH'
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

So far, so good. But then you need to create a date from this.

```
Date date = new Date(finalTimeStamp * 1000L)
```

Then, you need to format what you need (and never EVER parse a date you just formatted. That makes no sense at all).

```
String finalCreatedTime = dateFormatter.format(date); // Not sure if you need this one
```

And

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String getTime = sdfTimeFormatter.format(date);
feeds.setTime(getTime);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So the changes you suggested will fix it eh? I have not been able to try it out yet. And probably wont for another day. So just asking...

Comment: +1 And accepting the answer as you helped with your pointer in any case. :-)